# Not understanding why text file contents are not being stored in individual elements of vector

Tags: c++

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <sstream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    ifstream inFile("test.txt");
    string line;

    while(getline(inFile, line))
    {
        istringstream meh(line);
        int n;
        vector<int> v;

        while(meh >> n)
            v.push_back(n);
    }
}
```

My test.txt file looks like:

```
429384
392041
230138
099938
243324
```

If I try to print v[0] I get the entire sequence of numbers back (42938...3324) instead of just the first number 4.  Can anyone explain why this is happening?

Comment: What you're saying makes no sense - since `v` is a vector of ints, `v[0]` must be a single int. Show the printing code.

Comment: why do you use istringstream? you should probably just loop through all the characters in the line. istringstream doesn't give you one character at a time but the whole word (number).

Comment: What should my bounds be for the loop? In other words, how do I know when the line ends?

Comment: if you just want the 4, you should try `char n` instead of `int n`

Comment: I don't want to treat the 4 as a character, though.

Comment: You can convert it if you want to. Btw, I assume that you are outputting v[0] right after the line of the `v.push_back(n);` without newline ?

Comment: Yes, that is what I was doing.  I just not realized why that was wrong.  But I used a for-loop and char/int conversion and got it working the way I wanted.  Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably made a mistake when you output your data.Your code stores in fact only one `int`-value for each line - the whole line was stored inside v[0]. Then you wrote that whole number inside a stream and forgot to write a new line before your while-loop started to process the next line. Thus, your output was one large number.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <sstream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    istringstream inFile("text.txt");
    string line;
    vector<vector<int> > vector_container;

    while(getline(inFile, line))
    {
        istringstream meh(line);
        char n;
        vector<int> v;

        while(meh >> n)
            v.push_back(static_cast<int>(n)-48);

        vector_container.push_back(v);
    }
    // this would output your numbers the way they were
    // stored inside your file
    for(int i = 0; i < vector_container.size(); ++i){
        for(int j = 0; j < vector_container[i].size(); ++j){
             cout << vector_container[i][j];
        }
        cout << endl;
    }

}
```

This should work the way you expected it to be. You will have a `vector<int>` container inside a `vector<vector<int> >`. The first one will store your number in a line, whereas each character will be stored individually. The latter vector simply stores the vectors for the numbers for your lines. The `char` to `int` conversion should explain itself when you take a look at the ASCII-table.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you correctly and you really want to loop through each digit within each line, then you could try this:

```c
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <sstream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

int main()
{   
    ifstream inFile("test.txt");
    string line;

    while(getline(inFile, line))
    {   
        vector<int> v;
        int n;
        // loop through the string
        for(int i = 0; i < line.length(); i++) {
           // check whether the byte is numeric
           if(line[i] >= '0' && line[i] <= '9') {
               // convert it to a real integer
               int n = line[i] - '0';
               v.push_back(n); // add it to the vector
           }   
        }   

        // just to show they have been added
        int j;
        for (vector<int>::size_type j = 0; j < v.size(); ++j) {   
            std::cout << v[j] << std::endl;
        }   
    }   
}
```

The vector **v** will only have the scope of the loop so each line of the file will have it's own vector; however this may be what you want, without knowing the actual application I cannot say anymore.